# Multiple tabs of application with Dexie

Tags: dexie

Currently i work on project which use lovefield library for wrapping indexedDb. And if open multiple tabs of application then database will be damaged(as lovefield not handle multiple connections to db). How about Dexie? Can i use it for multiple tabs in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with Dexie. Here it is best to use the `liveQuery` to update your UI directly as soon as something has changed.

There is a good example from Dexie itself:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4666q1